# Opening link in new tab results in problem with ajax

Tags: html, ajax

I want to open a link in a new tab and wrote this line of code:

```
<a href="https://www.google.de/" class="downloadButton" target="_blank">DOWNLOADEN</a>
```

I get this error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYkZG.png

Seems like theres a problem with ajax, which i use in the file aswell.
But i dont understand why such a basic command causes trouble and i dont know how to fix it.

Comment: The code has nothing to do with the error. Seems that the error is a loaded problem of the jquery file

Comment: If it's the only thing he changed and it resulted in the error then it does have something to do with the error. What we don't have is enough info to figure why it causes an error. OP why don't you post the script part that triggers the jquery ajax call?